# Why is the enemy healthbar being retargeted?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been having a small host of glitches in Skyrim lately, and I'm hoping to fix one of them here.

Whenever I fight multiple enemies, the enemy health bar display remains locked on whatever enemy I am not fighting. If there are two enemies and I attack one, it shows me the health bar for the other. Health goes down properly and everything, but it makes combat very difficult, as I can never tell if my enemy is about to drop or not (which come to think of it is more immersive).

This glitch did surface fairly recently, so it could be the result of a mod. My recent mods are Deadly Dragons and the SkyUI. I have made changes to the stats of all NPCs through the 'Deadly Monsters' extension of Deadly Dragons (I'm guessing it was an extension - the mod page said nothing about it).

Less recent mods (I can't remember exactly when the glitch surfaced, so these might have affected it as well) are Fantasy Soundtrack Project, Immersive Patrols, and PerMa Weaponry Fillout. I am using Perkus Maximus, but I literally started the entire game with Perkus, so I doubt that is the problem. I also use SKSE, but again, I started the game with that.

Is there a known fix for this issue? Someone else did have the issue [here](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/2168814-weird-target-health-bar-bug/?p=20727524), but with no fix. He actually said nothing can be done, which I find a little hard to believe in a game with so many console commands and open code. Surely there's work-a-around?

Comment: Why dont you try installing the unnoficial skyrim patch? maybe that would help, but remember to save before installing anything else. :)

Answer (score -1):

I found this to be a problem too,fighting two enemies simultaneously causes the game to glitch and only show one of the opponent's health bar,I chose to ignore this.I simply just have to find who the health bar belongs to and focus on him,but it hasn't been much of a problem because I always attack one person at a time 
Hope this helped :)